# Scala Inheritance (Too Many Arguments For Constructor)

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to extend a CSVReader that I found at

https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/tototoshi/csv/CSVReader.scala

I wrote the following bare bones shell of a class:

```
class CSVOtherReader(reader: Reader, format: CSVFormat) 
extends CSVReader(reader, format)     {

}
```

Which gives me the error that there are:

```
too many arguments for constructor CSVReader: (reader: java.io.Reader)(implicit 
format: com.github.tototoshi.csv.CSVFormat)com.github.tototoshi.csv.CSVReader
```

This class was created directly from the Scala IDE Eclipse Plugin by creating a new class, marking it as inheriting from a superclass and directly pointing to the CSVReader class.  Because of this, I feel that the syntax should be correct, but I'm wondering in what cases this might not work.  Is there something about the parent class (found at the github link) that would prevent me from doing this?  A quick look at inheritance in Scala makes it seem like this syntax is correct.

-Arjun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the source of the CSVReader class you can see that it has two separate parameter lists. So the correct syntax would be:

```
class CSVOtherReader(reader: Reader, format: CSVFormat) 
    extends CSVReader(reader)(format)     {

}
```

or, if you want to retain the implicit parameter for convenience in your subclass:

```
class CSVOtherReader(reader: Reader)(implicit format: CSVFormat)
    extends CSVReader(reader)(format)     {

}
```

The IDE is apparently not correctly dealing with the separate parameter lists here.

Comment: Thanks that was an easy fix.  I'll try to file something against this behavior.

Comment: I had similar issue when the superclass has `@Inject()()()` construct. Still requires two parameter lists.